# GWT Clipboard Past Buffer

Tags: java, gwt, clipboarddata

I maintain a GWT web application.  Our users often upload screen shot image files via a standard file upload dialog.  I'm trying to think of some slightly more user friendly approach.  I was wondering if there might be any way to allow the users to "paste" the image data after clicking the print-screen button.

I read some other posts that said that GWT can't nativly copy anything to or read from the clipboard buffer, but what about if the user manually pastes the image via ctrl-V or right clicking and pasting.

If anybody knows how I can accomplish this in GWT or has any other ideas let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for pasting:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.ONPASTE
```

I use this but only for pasting text (user must user Ctrl+V or right-click>Paste).
I guess there may be a way for you to use this.

To capture the event, I sink it to my Widget first:

```
sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE | Event.ONKEYPRESS | Event.ONKEYDOWN | Event.ONFOCUS);
```

Then, I implement onBrowserEvent(Event):

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
    case Event.ONPASTE: paste(event);
    }
}
```

Hope you can find a way to adapt this for images.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot.  The event is firing for me when pasting an image.  Once I have the Event object is there a way to read the pasted data from it?  If I'm pasting text to a TextBox I can just read the text box's text, but pasting images doesn't add any text.